# Trapped and invisible; what am I?

Tags: riddle

I have no legs, but I can move with ease
I am trapped, yet I can go where your eyes can see
I am invisible, until you find me
I am a thing, that you will wish to set free

Comment: hmm, love maybe?

Comment: No not love, thou it is one of the expected guesses~

Comment: An old pinewood derby car inside a box in a storage unit? :P

Comment: A Letter or air

Comment: I just approved @AshutoshNigam's edit since I don't *think* it changes anything important, but please check to make sure the meaning of the riddle is still the same.

Comment: Lots of great answers this question is attracting!

Comment: Ok, pardon me but what about FART?

Comment: @me_digvijay, it is good with all lines but second one (as it has limited range but eyes can see things miles away ) ;)

Comment: @AshutoshNigam: the second line itself says "I am trapped", so by that logic: if it is trapped inside it can go for distances miles away(still trapped)

Comment: I am thinking [floaters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floater). Floaters don't have legs but can move easily around your eyes. They are trapped in the fluid around your eye, are invisible until you really focus on them, and there are procedures to get rid of them.

Comment: @randal'thor thanks I didn't know this riddle could bring so much ppl!

Comment: Alright we've a winner here but I didn't accept answer, cuz it's lack of explanation.

Comment: Was it Mine?    I'll flesh it out.

Comment: @Jiminion yours another good guess but nope =D

Comment: Right, figured that out.

Comment: @Alex - Consistent with site practices, I have changed your title to be more unique.  If you would like something different, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the answer is...

> Eye floaters

I have no legs, but I can move with ease

> They move around everywhere you look

I am trapped, yet I can go where your eyes can see

> [They are inside your eyeball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floater)

I am invisible, until you find me

> You don't always notice them, until you do

I am a thing, that you will wish to set free

> They are annoying, you want them to get out of your eye

Comment: Haha :D first riddle I've answered

Comment: And this is my first riddle on SE!  There are alot of great riddle out there, go try them they're great

Answer (score 12):

I think you are

> Light

I have no legs, but I can move in ease

> Light has the fastest possible speed. Nothing can beat its top speed.

I am trapped, yet I can go where your eyes can see

> It can be confined in a enclosed space like a building, but you can still see as long there is a light source. You need light to see.

I am invisible, until you have found me

> You can't really see light. There are phrases like "I have seen the light" and lines like that. The entrance to heaven to many is seen as big entrance door thingy made of light I think.

I am a thing, that you will wish to set me free

> You will want to see by letting light roam around. Lighting candles and turning on lamps and flashlights could "release the light".

Comment: Nice one! That's probably it.

Comment: Yippee!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I was actually thinking about darkness.

Comment: This answer is actually so close, except it still didn't fit in with line 2

Comment: This was my answer as well, I understood line 2 as "I am trapped" -- i.e. blocked by most materials, "yet I can go where your eyes can see" -- i.e. wherever you can see, light can go there, since if light can't go there you can't see there

Answer (score 5):

How about

> beauty

Seems to fit everything, particularly the 4th line.

*I have no legs, but I can move in ease*

> Beauty doesn't walk, but *moves in ease*, ie it lives in things that are easy

*I am trapped, yet I can go where your eyes can see*

> Beauty is in the eye of the beholder

*I am invisible, until you have found me*

> It's not always apparent what is beautiful on first sight.

*I am a thing, that you will wish to set me free*

> Beauty is a thing, not necessarily a property. But there is also a compulsion to set it free.

Comment: Didn't quite explain line 1 but good guess!

Answer (score 4):

Is it

> dust?

I have no legs, but I can move in ease

> it floats around in the air at the slightest breeze

I am trapped, yet I can go where your eyes can see

> Dust is confined to whatever space its in. Also its all around you (more or less depending on how clean the area is)

I am invisible, until you have found me

> can be hard to see until you focus on it. Also dependent on how clean your place is :)

I am a thing, that you will wish to set me free

> By set free maybe you want to wipe it with a wet rag and wash it down the sink?

Answer (score 4):

What about

> Fart

I have no legs, but I can move with ease

> Once you release it, it spreads

I am trapped, yet I can go where your eyes can see

> Previous explanation, it fills the room - everywhere that you can see

I am invisible, until you find me

> It is invisible, but if you have suspicion, you can just get a match or lighter and set it on fire.

I am a thing, that you will wish to set free

> Of course!

Comment: hahahaha it fits perfectly with line 4, but it's still invisible (at least not detected by our eyes heh)

Comment: It is visible if you set it on fire.

Answer (score 3):

Could it possibly be

> A reflection

I have no legs, but I can move in ease

> A reflection moves easily with changing light

I am trapped, yet I can go where your eyes can see

> it is trapped in a mirror, but you can see the reflection of the room behind you for example

I am invisible, until you have found me

> You cannot see your own reflection until you are looking right at the mirror

I am a thing, that you will wish to set me free

> You will want to release yourself from the mirror

Comment: I really like your answer, though it didn't fit line 1 and 4 well

Answer (score 3):

I have no legs, but I can move with ease

> Imagination can go any where

I am trapped, yet I can go where your eyes can see

> Imagination can be trapped in anything you see

I am invisible, until you find me

> You might be lost in imagination unless you realize you in trance

I am a thing, that you will wish to set free

> You want to always set your Imagination free to get best out of your capabilities

Answer (score 3):

I think its

> White Blood Cells ([blue-sky sprites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_field_entoptic_phenomenon)), which appear when you look up at the sky

I have no legs, but I can move with ease

> They move in the body mixed with blood

I am trapped, yet I can go where your eyes can see

> Trapped inside your eye (or body), and wherever you see in the sky, it seems they follow you

I am invisible, until you find me

> You don't notice them until you look at a clear blue sky and you have to pay proper attention to see it

I am a thing, that you will wish to set free

> White Blood Cells eventually are disposed out from the body and new ones are formed, maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting.. First thing that comes in my mind is

> the mind

I have no legs, but I can move in ease

> focusing on different tasks, mind wandering..

I am trapped, yet I can go where your eyes can see

> it is trapped in your head, yet it can be everywhere you imagine

I am invisible, until you have found me

> because mind is invisible??

I am a thing, that you will wish to set me free

> set free your mind meaning escape the problems and daily worries

Comment: Good guess! But nope it's not the answer.  Mind will be still invisible if you found it after losing it heh

Comment: well, not if you're aware of it ;) there's a lot of room for interpretations in this 3rd line.. anyway, great riddle, it sounds like coming from a fairytale.

Comment: It is actually visible once you 'found' it!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the solution to this is something disgusting.

I'm thinking about

> a Parasite

I have no legs, but I can move with ease

> Inside the body of its victim

I am trapped, yet I can go where your eyes can see

> trapped inside the body of the victim, but can be at the same place the body wants to be, since its moving with it.

I am invisible, until you find me

> You don't know its there, until you (maybe) notice its presence

I am a thing, that you will wish to set free

> if you get to know you have something like this, you probably want to get rid of it.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be

> Heart/Feelings

I have no legs, but I can move with ease

> You can move someone's heart with words

I am trapped, yet I can go where your eyes can see

> Trapped within your chest, but it can be affected by anything you see

I am invisible, until you find me

> You do not realise your feelings until you find them

I am a thing, that you will wish to set free

> Relating to love possibly?

Answer (score 2):

> Imagination

Seems to fit pretty well.

I have no legs, but I can move with ease

> Imagination has no limits or boundaries

I am trapped, yet I can go where your eyes can see

> But sometimes it can be trapped by your own thinking, but what you see or experience can free it

I am invisible, until you find me

> Sometimes it can be hard to find your "muse" and can be invisible to you.

I am a thing, that you will wish to set free

> A strong imagination has no limits and can free you from any prison, real or imagined.

Answer (score 1):

> Your gaze

fits everything except possibly the last line.

*I have no legs, but I can move in ease*

> Your gaze can roam around anywhere.

*I am trapped, yet I can go where your eyes can see*

> It's trapped to be just at the place where you're looking.

*I am invisible, until you have found me*

> You can't see that someone else is looking at you until you meet their gaze.

*I am a thing, that you will wish to set me free*

> Stop staring at me!

Comment: Good guess!  But nope it's not the answer, last line doesn't match as you mentioned

Comment: @Alex A slight variation: SIGHT? When you've "found" your sight, nothing is invisible any more, so the 3rd line fits better than with GAZE.

Comment: This and the other answer 'light' is the closest, but still not the answer!

Answer (score 1):

How about

> The woman I have trapped in my basement

I have no legs, but I can move with ease

> I cut her legs off but she got pretty good with walking on her hands

I am trapped, yet I can go where your eyes can see

> Shes in a big cage but has a TV

I am invisible, until you find me

> No one knows shes here

I am a thing, that you will wish to set free

> You want to free her because there's a good ransom

Feel free to down vote me ;)

Comment: -1 But what about the one I have in my basement... it's not a unique answer...

Comment: Ah damn, I didn't think of that!

Comment: What kind of ransom are you expecting in lieu of a hostage minus her legs?

Comment: WTF? Why feel free to downvote me?

Comment: @FollowMyProposals Well, it's a bit of a silly and non-serious answer. But +1 from me for sheer cheek :-)

Comment: @randal'thor :-)

Answer (score 1):

You might be

> a jelly fish

I have no legs, but I can move with ease

> they have tentacles not legs

I am trapped, yet I can go where your eyes can see

> trapped in the ocean, go can do to oceans' depth

I am invisible, until you find me

> there is a famous species of jelly fish that are nearly invisible in water

I am a thing, that you will wish to set free

> jelly fish not in the wild: you want to set free

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

> The Horizon.

I have no legs, but I can move with ease:

> Explanation - The horizon keeps moving

I am trapped, yet I can go where your eyes can see:

> Explanation - The horizon is as far as your eyes can see, and if you don't move it doesn't move

I am invisible, until you find me:

> Explanation - You can't see the horizon until you look up

I am a thing, that you will wish to set free:

> Explanation - Don't you want to expand your horizons, don't you want to fly?

Answer (score 0):

> A look, as in "he gave me a *look*"

It has no legs, moves with ease

It is trapped, but can move

> A look is confined to line of sight. Also, refers to the other meaning of look: to *look* around the room.

It is invisible until seen

> Back to the first meaning,  quite literally isn't seen until it's been looked at (but still exists if not seen).

It is a thing, and you want to set it free

> If you notice someone giving you a *look*,  you want to look away (ie set the look free).